# Express server inside a Expo typscript project throws error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, jsx, ts-node

I'm trying to set up an express server inside an expo ts project. The project uses all the defaults of a normal expo project.

I'm using `ts-node` to start the server file, which works with a basic server. But when I try to use JSX-syntax like `<div>Test</div>`, I get the following error:

```html
return <div>Test</div>;
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

I have React code on my server because I want to experiment with ReactDOMServer, so I intend to use react-dom and react-native together in one project.

My `tsconfig.json` looks as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: how about adding round brackets like this ?`return ()`